# TableView didSelectRowAt not triggered when interacting with TextField inside a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have encountered an issue where the didSelectRowAt method of my TableView is not triggered when I click inside a TextField that is placed inside a TableViewCell. Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
         // do something
         tableView.beginUpdates()
         tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

I would like to know the solution to fix this problem and ensure that the didSelectRowAt method is called even when interacting with the TextField inside the TableViewCell. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The image below illustrates the view structure and hierarchy.
[image: Text field is inside a table view cell]

Comment: By default, when a TextField or any other control is present in a UITableViewCell, it consumes the touch events, preventing the didSelectRowAt method from being called.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method is specifically designed to be called when user selects a cell. Selecting a cell is a specific action which does not include interactions with items on that cells (such as buttons or text fields). So you may have trouble forcing this component to trigger some event for you.

However, there should be many other options to solve whatever you are doing. Some more insight into what you are building would help but some of the approaches may be:

**Option one:** Assign a delegate to the text field inside the table view cell and let the delegate trigger the event you want:

```
extension UIViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    private func onRowSelected(at: IndexPath) {

    }

    public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let indexPath = rowForCellWithMyTextField()
        tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow == indexPath || tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.contains(indexPath) == true {
            // already selected
        } else {
            UITableView().selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
            onRowSelected(at: indexPath)
        }
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        ...
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        onRowSelected(at: indexPath)
    }

}
```

**Option two:** Disallow interactions on your components within the table view cell. By disabling user interaction on your text field any touch will go through and the cell will be selected as if it was pressed outside the text field. All you then need is to enable/disable user interaction when cell should start/stop editing.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let textFieldCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTextFieldCell {
            textFieldCell.textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

and

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

**Option three:** Avoid using native tool for table view cell selection. There is no need for you to really use the internal mechanism for selection if the mechanism does not suit your needs. Simply create your own storage for selected cells and update your cells by yourself however you want it.

```
var selectedCells: Set<IndexPath> = .init()
```